# Adding Maven dependency to Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I need to add a Maven plugin to my Eclipse.

When I browsed Eclipse Market Place, there were loads of Maven dependencies, and some of them didn't work.

Which would you suggest?

Comment: Do you mean that you need a Maven plugin so that Eclipse can use maven with your project?

Comment: Yes, I need to add a Maven plugin to Eclipse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your eclipse go to Help ->Install New Software and use this update site to install Maven:
http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases

Answer (score 7):

I recommend you download the M2Eclipse plugin, it can be found on this link:
http://eclipse.org/m2e/

There is also a demo movie of what it does and how simple it is.